# Artifactory OSS: What's the recommended build cleanup strategy?

Tags: api, artifactory

Since the API call to delete builds requires Artifactory Pro, what's the recommended way to cleanup old builds in the OSS version?
Also the build retention setting in Jenkins seems to have no effect in the OSS version. Is there another (more automated) approach in OSS beside deleting old builds manually from the UI?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OSS version you can only delete builds from the UI, as you mentioned.